# How to solve Method "POST" not allowed 405

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm using Django Rest Framework for API and I faced this problem. In `views.py` my class inherits from `ModelViewSet`, but for some reason it doesn't allow making a `POST` request. For frontend I'm using React JS and I make a POST request from there. And in the end I'm getting an error like this: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/3/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

Here's `views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from .serializers import (
    CategorySerializer,
    SoftwareSerializer,
    SoftwareListRetrieveSerializer,
    CategoryDetailSerializer,
    CustomPaginatorSerializer
)
from ..models import Category, Software


class CategoryViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    pagination_class = None

    action_to_serializer = {
        "retrieve": CategoryDetailSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.action_to_serializer.get(
            self.action,
            self.serializer_class
        )


class SoftwareViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Software.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SoftwareSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPaginatorSerializer

    action_to_serializer = {
        "list": SoftwareListRetrieveSerializer,
        "retrieve": SoftwareListRetrieveSerializer
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.action_to_serializer.get(
            self.action,
            self.serializer_class
        )
```

Here's `urls.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import CategoryViewSet, SoftwareViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('category', CategoryViewSet, basename='category')
router.register('software', SoftwareViewSet, basename='software')

urlpatterns = []
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: You need to use `PUT` or `PATCH`

Comment: `PUT` doesn't work, throws an error: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/3/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: `PATCH` worked, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/3/** , it looks like a detail of a data, you can only use **PUT** or **Patch** in details, no POST method is allowed.

Comment: `PUT` doesn't work, throws an error: PUT 127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/3 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: PUT doesn't work maybe just because you didn't provide a full data for it to update, PUT is fully-update operation while PATCH is partial-update operation.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/3/` is calling the **retrieve** method and this method must be called through GET.